# scala uanpply without parameter

Tags: scala, parameters, unapply

I am a student who studies Scala in korea. I am learning about pattern matching and unapply methods. The thing I am confused about is that **Emergency** object has a parameter in unapply method. I can't know the reason when I don't put the parameter in the match block.

```
object Solution {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val number1 = "010-123-1234"
    val number2 = "119"
    val number3 = "포도먹은 돼지"
    val numberList = List(number1, number2, number3)

    for (number <- numberList) {
      number match {
        case Emergency() => println("긴급전화다")
        case Normal(number) => println("일반 전화다" + number)
        case _ => println("판단할 수 없습니다.")
      }
    }
  }
}

object Emergency {
  def unapply(number: String): Boolean = {
    if (number.length == 3 && number.forall(_.isDigit)) true
    else false
  }
}

object Normal {
  def unapply(number: String): Option[Int] = {
    try {
      Some(number.replaceAll("-", "").toInt)
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => None
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that return types of to `unapply` methods are different.

`Normal.unapply` returns an `Option`. When you do `case Normal(foo)`, `unapply` is called, and, if it returns `Some(number)`, the match is successful, and the `number` is assigned to local variable `foo`, and if it returns `None`, match fails.

`Emergency.unapply` returns a `Boolean`, so `case Emergency()` succeeds if it returns `true`, and fails otherwise, but there is no result to assign in case of success, thus, no "parameter".

Comment: Sorry. I got the Normal part but what does "no result to assign in case of success" means?? Does it mean that if i have a return value I have to put the parameter in?? Boolean is also an return value. Am I thinking it wrong??

Comment: `Normal(foo)` returns an `Int`, that gets assigned to `foo`. `Emergency()` does not need a parameter: `true` matches the case clause, `false` does not.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in unapply is the object on which you are matching.

In this case the `number` String variable is passed to `Emergency.unapply`, `Normal.unapply` etc.

This link explains things nicely:

https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html

Comment: I understood that. What I am confused about is that **Emergency** object has a parameter in the unapply method. but why does it work without the parameter

Comment: The answer above explains that.